# How to use square brackets to jump over HTML tags

Tags: vim

I'm using `[[` and `]]` to jump between classes in Python. I also want to jump between HTML tags that are in the same indentation level.

For example:

```
<div>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
</div>
<div>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
</div>
```

If the cursor on the first div element, it should go to second `div` when I press `]]`. If the cursor on the `li` element, it should go to next `li` element and then the next `div` element.

How I map it in the .vimrc?

Answer (score 1):

**When <kbd>,</kbd> is pressed in normal mode, move to next `<div` if cursor is on `<div>`, otherwise move to next `<li` or `<div`**

if on cursor on `<div`, go to next `<div`. Otherwise go to next `<li` or `<div`

```
function! NextTag()
  call search( getline('.') =~? 'div' ? '<div' : '<\(li\|div\)')
endfunction

nnoremap , :call NextTag()<cr>
```

Add the above in your vimrc with `:e $MYVIMRC` and reload it with `:source $MYVIMRC`

Assumptions: A simple tag structure like the example you posted.  May not work as expected with nested div's and li's. div's and li's do not appear on the same line